# Transitive Relations and functions

Tags: functions, relations, equivalence-relations

A function by definition is a relation in which no two ordered pairs have the same first element, and every element in domain has an image in codomain.
A relaton $R$ is transitive if for all values $a, b, c$: $a R b$ and $b R c$ implies $a R c$.
So does it mean a function can never be transitive ?

Comment: It requires that if $f(a)=b$ and $f(b)=c$ then $f(a)=c$ but that requires $b=c$. We can have a function $f:\{a,b,c,d,e,h\}$ where $f(a)=b;f(b)=b; f(c)=d; f(d)=d; f(e)=h;f(h)=h$. And that'd be transitive.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite, but close.  The function $f:X \to X$ defined by $f(x)=x$ is a transitive relation.  Your proof fails because you don't know that $b \neq c$.

**Edited to add:**

I believe your proof does show that $f$ is a transitive relation $\iff f \circ f = f$.

Comment: another counter example is the empty function.

Comment: Is this just the identity function you have described @Robert Shore? Thanks!

Comment: @CormJack That's correct.  That's the only function that is also (considered as a relation) an equivalence relation.

Comment: Thank you very much @Robert Shore. I've actually just done a bit of a meta post about Transitive Relations and Functions, trying to piece together the input from different threads. And ask unsatisfied questions. Your answer also very helpfully features: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597979/relations-transitive-functions-idempotent-functions